How to re-mean a vector of probabilities, without having values beyond the [0, 1] bounds?
Imagine we have a vector of probabilities, $x$. Its mean is $\bar{x}$. Now, let's say there is an arbitrary value between 0 and 1 that we would like to re-mean the vector to. That's some given proportion, $p$.
What I would like to do is go from $x$ to $x'$ where $\bar{x'} = p$. However, these represent probabilities, so $x' \in [0, 1]$ also needs to be satisfied. Additionally, $x'$ needs to retain the relative rank ordering of $x$.
One way of doing this would be to simply de-mean the variable and add back $p$:
$x' = x - \bar{x} + p$
However, this will force values to be below 0 or above 1, so not representing probabilities anymore.
Another way of doing this is taking both $x$ and $p$ into logit space, doing the re-meaning there, and then bringing it back out. For shorthand, I'm using $logit$ as the logistic function and $invlogit$ as its inverse:
$x' = invlogit(logit(x) - \overline{logit(x)} + logit(p))$
However, the mean in probability space will no longer be $p$.
How can I re-mean a vector of probabilities, without having values beyond the [0, 1] bounds?
Below is a demonstration in R.
remean <- function(x, p) x - mean(x) + p

remean_logit <- function(x, p) {
  x <- qlogis(x)
  x <- x - mean(x) + qlogis(p)
  return(plogis(x))
}


set.seed(1839)
p <- .56
x <- runif(1000)

summary(x) # mean is .497
summary(remean(x, p)) # mean is correct, but max > 1
summary(remean_logit(x, p)) # values within 0 and 1, but mean is incorrect


What do you mean be "re-mean"?

Instead of de-meaning (making the mean be 0) or mean-centering (making the mean be 1), I want to rescale the variable such that the mean is equal to some arbitrary number, $p$. As I mention above: What I would like to do is go from $x$ to $x'$ where $\bar{x'} = p$.

Setting all $x=p$ has the mean $p$, but presumably you also want to preserve some other qualities of the data, such as their relative ordering. So a completely general solution is $p = \sigma(ax+b)$ where $a >0$ and $b$ is any real number and $\sigma(y) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-y)}$. You can adjust $a,b$ to get any mean $ 0 < p <1$ you desire.

@Sycorax that would work, but how does one re-arrange what you have there to solve for the average instead of solve for $p$?

Minimizing $\epsilon_i$ in $\sigma^{-1}(p) = ax_i + b + \epsilon_i$ is just linear regression...

Apologies if I'm being dense, but what's tripping me up there is that $p$ is a constant while $x$ varies. So how does one do linear regression there? I.e., with the example I gave in R below, lm(plogis(p) ~ x) throws an error because the lengths of p and x are different.

@Sycorax I misspoke in the earlier comment—how do you re-arrange it to get the values of $a$ and $b$, with a known $p$? I see how you could solve it using linear regression, but usually the other side of the equation would have a subscript $i$
as well, whereas here it is a fixed value. How does one solve for $a$ and $b$ then?

"However, this will force values to be below 0 or above 1, so not representing probabilities anymore" - I don't see any particular reason why the end result should represent probabilities. The simple fact that the transformation puts everything in the range [0, 1] says nothing about whether those values have any probabilistic interpretation whatsoever. Say you have a weather forecast with the probability of rain for the next week, and you want to adjust it by some value p. The "re-meaned" values aren't calibrated probabilities and say little about the actual chance of rain.

The constraint on the mean is a 1D constraint on a countably infinite space of functions, so those requesting additional desiderata are putting it mildly!  There's a huge array of solutions.

Each $X$ has the same $p$. So the regression has $n$ copies of $p$ as the outcome. Or, if you like, $p_i=p$.

I get the feeling this is an XY problem. It might help to explain the underlying problem this "remeaning" is attempting to solve, so that we can help identify good ways to solve the actual problem rather than solving the "problem" with your attempted solution to your original problem.

In a comment below the accepted answer, you mentioned that you have edited an additional constraint on the ordering of $x_i$ into your question. I am interested in your motivation. Would it be possible to share the underlying story?

I've got probabilistic scores on folks before an event. After the event, I know what the true rate was for a specific group. The idea is to adjust these a priori scores such that their group mean is equal to what we know is the truth after the event. This is only one solution I'm considering for how to adjust with that the actual rate; thus, my question here deliberately asks about a specific solution because I was getting tripped up on implemention. The optimization on minimizing squared difference for various possible adjustments in logit space answered precisely what I was trying to do.

In summary, I'm acknowledging other solutions do exist (I am looking into a handful), but my specific question was on this particular approach, which I will be using to compare to other methods.

As Sycorax mentioned, there are probably other desiderata you have in mind that you haven't made explicit, but here's something to get us started:
find the offset in logit space, but minimize the mean in proportion space.
Here's what I mean. Let $x' = \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(x)+\eta)$, and solve numerically for $\eta$ such that $\bar{x}' = p$.
Quick example in R:
x <- rbeta(10,1,1) # Input data
print(mean(x)) # Existing mean
p <- 0.69 # Desired mean
cost <- function(eta) (mean(plogis(qlogis(x) + eta))-p)^2

eta_opt <- optimize(cost, interval = c(-10,10))$minimum
xprime <- plogis(qlogis(x) + eta_opt)
print(mean(xprime)) # Mean as desired.


Makes sense with what I'm looking for, thank you. For future reference, I edited the original post to also include that I'm wanting to retain the relative rank ordering of values.

To summarize the goal as presented in the question, starting with a vector $x\in[0,1]$, perform a transformation $f(x)=x'$ such that:

$x'\in[0,1]$
$\bar{x'}=p$, where $p\in[0,1]$
If $x_i>x_j$, then $x'_i>x'_j$ ($f$ is an increasing function)

There are myriad transformations that can accomplish this. One general strategy is to transform $x$ to the positive reals via some function $g$, multiply the transformed values by a positive constant, $a$, and then invert the transformation:
$$x'=g^{-1}(a\cdot g(x))$$
Alternatively, transform $x$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$, add or subtract $a$, and then invert the transformation.
Notice that $g$ can be the quantile function of any distribution with support on $[0,\infty)$ (or $(-\infty,\infty)$). A few examples:

Exponential distribution: $g(x)=-\ln(x)$ (which results in $x'=x^a$)
Log-logistic distribution: $g(x)=x/(1-x)$
Half-Cauchy distribution: $g(x)=\text{tan}(\pi x/2)$

Each will behave a little differently, so choose a transformation that has desirable properties for what you are doing.
Demonstrating in R:
set.seed(1839)
x <- runif(1000)
p <- 0.56
np <- p*length(x)
f <- vector("list", 6)

# log-logistic
f[[1]] <- function(a) (y <- a^2/(1/x - 1))/(y + 1)
# exponential
f[[2]] <- function(a) pexp(qexp(x, exp(a)))
# gamma
f[[3]] <- function(a) pgamma(qgamma(x, 1, 1), 1, exp(a))
# chi-squared
f[[4]] <- function(a) pchisq(exp(a)*qchisq(x, 1), 1)
# log-normal
f[[5]] <- function(a) plnorm(exp(a)*qlnorm(x))
# normal
f[[6]] <- function(a) pnorm(qnorm(x), a)

a <- sapply(f, \(f) uniroot(\(a) sum(f(a)) - np, 0:1, extendInt = "yes",
                            tol = 1e-9)$root)
y <- lapply(1:length(f), \(i) f[[i]](a[i]))
max(abs(sapply(y, mean) - p))
#> [1] 4.24305e-11
r <- rank(x)
all(sapply(y, \(y) all.equal(rank(y), r)))
#> [1] TRUE

Another consideration is efficiency when implemented in code. Here are a few candidate functions in R to benchmark.
remean1 <- function(x, p, np = p*length(x)) {
  x^uniroot(\(r) sum(x^r) - np, log(p)/log(range(x)), tol = 1e-9)$root
}

remean2 <- function(x, p, np = p*length(x)) {
  a <- uniroot(\(a) sum((y <- a/(1/x - 1))/(y + 1)) - np,
               (1/p - 1)/(1/range(x) - 1), tol = 1e-9)$root
  (y <- a/(1/x - 1))/(y + 1)
}

remean3 <- function(x, p, np = p*length(x)) {
  a <- uniroot(\(a) 2*sum(atan(tan(x*pi/2)/a))/pi - np,
               atanh(range(x))/atanh(p), tol = 1e-9)$root
  2*atan(tan(x*pi/2)/a)/pi
}

remean4 <- function(x, p, np = p*length(x)) {
  a <- uniroot(\(a) sum(tanh(atanh(x)/a)) - np,
               atanh(range(x))/atanh(p), tol = 1e-9)$root
  tanh(atanh(x)/a)
}

mean(remean1(x, p)) - p
#> [1] -2.251033e-11
mean(remean2(x, p)) - p
#> [1] 0
mean(remean3(x, p)) - p
#> [1] -9.473866e-12
mean(remean4(x, p)) - p
#> [1] -4.674039e-14

Benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  remean1(x, p),
  remean2(x, p),
  remean3(x, p),
  remean4(x, p)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>  remean1(x, p) 2117.7 2176.00 2504.393 2236.10 2475.75 15133.2   100
#>  remean2(x, p)  237.0  336.30  391.087  351.55  400.60  1573.0   100
#>  remean3(x, p)  513.0  569.80  816.528  593.15  660.60 13371.0   100
#>  remean4(x, p)  702.0  759.95  988.719  781.40  950.65 10681.8   100


Why would one prefer this method? What problem does it solve that isn’t solved by the other answer? Are there any disadvantages to using it? OP asks for transformations that look like adding a constant, which is not what this answer proposes, so the (subjective) claim that it’s “simpler” doesn’t seem like a relevant differentiation.

I get you. See the updated answer. The motivation behind the original answer was to point out that there is more than one way to accomplish the task. Also, I don't read the question as the OP asking for additive transformations--that was just one approach that the OP had (unsuccessfully) explored.
